# SSMS silent install does not work due to forced restart

Tags: sql-server, ssms, inno-setup

Why is restarting the machine necessary for the silent installation of SQL Server Management Studio even when the /norestart argument is used? I'm installing from InnoSetup this way

```
 ShellExec(Verb, ExpandConstant('{syswow64}\cmd.exe'), 
'/C ' + 'start /w SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log "SSMS_logs/ssms-logs.log"', '', WShow, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Err);
```

and the logs reads that the installation was stopped due to pending restart.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What log? What installation? SSMS log/installation? Or Inno Setup log/installation? Show us the log.

Comment: If `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` exists then it had to install a dependency that requires a restart, such has hot fixes for Visual Studio Tools for Applications or SQL Server Management Studio Extensions. This could happen if there are previous versions of the tools installed - or remnants from a prior installation. The log file should tell which component required the restart.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Building on top of AlwaysLearning, the solution i found was to only install on systems that don't require a restart. If that does not work for you try this workaround: [enter link description here](https://richardstk.com/2012/03/07/pending-file-rename-workaround/)